# OpenGL compute shader not changing buffer

Tags: c, opengl, shader

I want to change the content of a buffer that i share between multiple shaders, in the compute shader. Specifically the normals in this case.

No matter what i set the value of one or more vertices in the buffer to, it doesn't seem to take effect in any of the other shaders. Probably i just forgot something or am not seeing something (I am new to compute shaders)

Here is the relevant part of the code. If you need more parts of the code, just ask. Please understand though that its hard to give a working piece of code because that requires quiet a bit more code than just a few lines.

```
utils_createComputeProgram(&g_simulateWaterProgram, "content/shaders/simulatewater/simulatewater.comp");

// Initialize first position buffer
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &app->positionBufferOne);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, app->positionBufferOne);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NUM_VERTICES*sizeof(MLvec4), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    MLvec4* positions = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i) {
        ...            
        positions[i] = mlMakeVec4(x, y, z, v);
    }

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

// Initialize second position buffer with 0
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &app->positionBufferTwo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, app->positionBufferTwo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NUM_VERTICES*sizeof(MLvec4), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    MLvec4* positions = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i) {
        positions[i] = mlMakeVec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

// initialize normal buffer
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &app->normalBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, app->normalBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NUM_VERTICES*sizeof(MLvec4), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    MLvec4* normals = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i) {
        normals[i] = mlMakeVec4(0, 0, 1, 0);
    }

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

// Attach buffers to program
{
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, app->positionBufferOne);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, app->positionBufferTwo);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, app->normalBuffer);
}

utils_createProgramVertexFragment(&g_renderWaterProgram, "content/shaders/renderwater/renderwater.vert", "content/shaders/renderwater/renderwater.frag");

// initialize VAO
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &g_waterVertexArrayObject);
    utils_setAttributePointer(g_waterVertexArrayObject, app->positionBufferOne, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    utils_setAttributePointer(g_waterVertexArrayObject, app->positionBufferTwo, 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);    
    utils_setAttributePointer(g_waterVertexArrayObject, app->normalBuffer, 2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}

// initialize index array
{
    ...
    glBindVertexArray(g_waterVertexArrayObject);
    glGenBuffers(1, &g_elementArrayBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_elementArrayBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * NUM_INDICES, g_waterIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void rendering_render(Application* app, int framebufferWidth, int framebufferHeight) {    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight);

    MLvec3 center = mlMakeVec3(app->camera.cx, app->camera.cy, app->camera.cz);
    MLvec3 eye = positionOfCamera(app->camera);

    MLmat4 modelMatrix = mlIdentity4;
    MLmat4 projectionMatrix = mlMakePerspectiveFromFOV(100, (float)framebufferWidth / framebufferHeight, 0.01, 100.0);
    MLmat4 viewMatrix = mlMakeLookAt(eye, center, mlMakeVec3(0, 1, 0));

    // Hier muss gewartet werden, bis der Compute Shader alle Schreiboperationen auf die Shader Storage Buffer ausgeführt hat.
    //glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BARRIER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(g_renderWaterProgram);

    utils_setUniformMat4(renderWaterProgram_ProjectionMatrix, &projectionMatrix);
    utils_setUniformMat4(renderWaterProgram_ViewMatrix, &viewMatrix);
    utils_setUniformMat4(renderWaterProgram_ModelMatrix, &modelMatrix);

    if (app->debug) {
        glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, NUM_INDICES, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    }
    else {
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_INDICES, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    }    

    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Compute shader:

```
layout (local_size_x = 1000, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout (location = 0) uniform float Dt; 

layout (std430, binding = 0) buffer PositionBufferOne {
vec4 positions[];
};

layout (std430, binding = 1) buffer PositionBufferTwo {
vec4 positionsNew[];
};

layout (std430, binding = 2) buffer NormalBuffer {
vec4 normals[];
};

vec3 calcNormal() {
return normalize(vec3(1, 1, 1));
}

void main() {
uint index = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
normals[index] = vec4(calcNormal(), 0.0);
}
```

utils:

```
GLuint utils_createShader(GLenum shaderType, const char* filename) {
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    const char* sources[2];
    sources[0] = common_readfile("content/shaders/utils.glsl");
    sources[1] = common_readfile(filename);

    glShaderSource(shader, 2, sources, NULL);
    free((void*)sources[0]);
    free((void*)sources[1]);

    glCompileShader(shader);
    utils_checkShaderLog(filename, shader);

    return shader;
}

void utils_createComputeProgram(GLuint *program, const char* computeShaderFilename) {
    glDeleteProgram(*program);

    GLuint computeShader = utils_createShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER, computeShaderFilename);

    *program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(*program, computeShader);

    glLinkProgram(*program);
    utils_checkProgramLog(*program);

    glDeleteShader(computeShader);
}

void utils_setAttributePointer(GLuint vertexArrayObject, GLuint buffer, GLint location, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized, GLsizei stride, unsigned offset) {
    GLint previousVertexArrayObject;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BINDING, &previousVertexArrayObject);
    GLint previousArrayBuffer;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &previousArrayBuffer);

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(location, size, type, normalized, stride, (void*)(intptr_t)offset);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, previousArrayBuffer);
    glBindVertexArray(previousVertexArrayObject);
}

void utils_setUniformMat4(GLuint location, MLmat4* m) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)m);
}
```

I tested changes by using the normals as the colors for my fragments.

In this example i set the normals to 0/0/0 during initialization and in the compute shader i change the value of every normal to normalized 1/1/1 thus expect so see the geometry in somewhat of a greyish color, but it stays black.

// EDIT

After starting from scratch and testing the result basically after every row of code i added i found out the problem was this line: glDispatchCompute(NUM_VERTICES / NUM_PARTICLES_PER_LOCAL_WORK_GROUP, 1, 1); i guess this evaluated to zero, which kind of makes sense with a "low" number of vertices and relatively high number of particles per work group.

That resulted in whatever i did in the compute shader was never actually being executed thus, not changing the buffer content.

Comment: You're not using the right memory barrier. YOu need to specify how the data is going to be used _after_ the barrier, so you need `GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BARRIER_BIT`. However, there is still a lot of code missing in your questiin, so I can't say if the GL state is set up correctly or not.

Comment: @derhass Can you tell me what extra information you would need? I wil then update the question with it. Also, i will try your suggestion later and report back.

Comment: Well, we'd actually need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Especially in a stabe-based API like OpenGL, it is very easy to screw something up in the code parts you have not included.